# Change the contact-form's html AFTER validation and mail sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a php powered contact-form for my page, where, after the submit button has been clicked AND (!) the mail has been sent, I would like to replace the content of the HTML. I could manage so far, that after `.btn` is clicked, the HTML gets replaces, but that happens before any validation would happen and the mail would be sent. Can you show me a way to do that please? Thanks a lot!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var newHTML = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="color:white; background-color:#6f8595; padding-bottom:15px; border-radius:5px;"><h3>Thank you for your message!<br />We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3></div>';
 
    $('.btn').click(function(){
     $('.form').html('').append(newHTML);
    });
});
```

```css
.contact-form {
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-bottom:70px;
}

.contact-form h1 {
 margin-bottom:70px;
}

.contact-form input {
 width:70%;
 margin:10px auto 20px auto;
}

.message textarea {
 max-width:80%;
 width:80%;
 margin:10px auto 20px auto;
 height:100px;
}

.contact-form .btn {
 background-color:#6f8595;
 color:white;
 transition:0.3s;
 width:50%;
}

.contact-form .btn:hover {
 background-color:white;
 color:#6f8595;
 transition:0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <form class="form clearfix" action="index.php" method="post">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <p>Name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your full name here" required>
  <p>Email:</p>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email here" required>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <p>Message:</p>
  <div class="message"><textarea name="message">Hello YourSite, </textarea></div>
  <div><input class="btn" type="submit" name="btn-submit" value="Send message!" required/></div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You will need ajax to do that

Comment: Yes, that much I know, haha :D But the question is HOW?

Comment: check [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Ajax to do this.

first we need a contact.php who will do the job and return a response to inform the client if the email has been sent or not.
for example:

**contact.php**

```
<?php
if (mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', 'message')) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => false]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['error' => true]);
}
```

Then in your client, you need to do an ajax request to the contact.php and update the dom depending on the response of the request :

**client.html**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var newHTML = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="color:white; background-color:#6f8595; padding-bottom:15px; border-radius:5px;"><h3>Thank you for your message!<br />We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3></div>';

    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $.post('contact.php', $('.form').serialize(), function () {
            if (data.error == false) {
                $('.form').html('').append(newHTML);
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>


    <form class="form clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Name:</p>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your full name here" required>
        <p>Email:</p>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email here" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Message:</p>
        <div class="message"><textarea name="message">Hello YourSite, </textarea></div>
        <div><input class="btn" type="submit" name="btn-submit" value="Send message!" required/></div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can see how can I validate the PHP part in JavaScript! :)

Comment: After using your code, it just simply redirects to the thankyou page, and if I take that redirecting header out, it reloads the page itself. What can be the problem? I would like to send the mail and change the form's html without reloading the site.

Comment: My php looks like: `if (isset($_POST["btn-submit"])) {
 $to = 'me@laszlovaszi.com';
 $from = $_POST['email'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $subject = 'YourSite Customer Email';
 $message = "<html><body>";
 $message .= $_POST["message"];
 $message .= "</body></html>";
 $headers = "From: ".$from. "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 header('Location: thankyou.html');
} `

Answer (score 2):

You should check if your form is valid before hiding the form. Try something like this using `valid()`:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    if($('.form').valid())
        $('.form').html('').append(newHTML);
});
```