# Validation not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have 3 section and each section there are some input filed with required validation.If i clicked on submit button required validation  not working and 1st section goes to 2nd section and same on 3rd section without validation.Please help  me in this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <style>
.m-div {display: none;}

.m-div.current {
  display: block;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">

  <section class="m-div current" id="one" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="bklet"  required/> 
    <label for="bklet"> check it</label>
</section>


<section class="m-div" id="two">
   <label> First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Fname" pattern=".{3,}" title="3 characters minimum"  class="input width-full" required>

    <label> Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Lname" pattern=".{3,}" title="3 characters minimum"  class="input width-full" required>              
</section>



<section class="m-div" id="three">
<label> Your Message</label>
<textarea class="textarea width-full" name="message" required></textarea>
</section>

<input type="submit" onclick="next();">

</form>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function next() {
  var current = $('.current');
  var next = current.next('.m-div:first');

  // loop back to the first div
  // if(next.length == 0) { next = $('#one'); }

  current.removeClass('current');
  next.addClass('current');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and the php is where *exactly?*

Comment: check my ans here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321862/change-the-contact-forms-html-after-validation-and-mail-sent/37322045#37322045

Comment: Sorry MR.Fred, I changed my question

Comment: Mr.Nishanath i checked your ans but still validation not working

Comment: I am not sure May be issue in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The validation attributes you applied to the form fields are just hints to the web browser. Each browser may display or handle such validations differently from other browsers.

For more information, I suggest reviewing a tutorial on the topic of HTML form validation, such as: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

**It's also important to note that form data can still be submitted regardless of these validations.** The validations you are using do nothing to ensure submitted data is present or valid. They can be easily bypassed by someone who wants to submit invalid data. Thus **you __must__ validate the submitted fields server side too!**